# Javascript in an HTML file, table with increasing cells per row

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table

I'm new to javascript and HTML, and I am looking to dynamicaly create a table with a loop in javascript inside of a HTML file.

I have the code to create a table, but I am struggling to get it to increase by one cell each row.

I feel as though I need to add `1` my cell variable each time the `for` loop runs, I assume its something like `cells++` but when ever I do this the html file wont load anything, any ideas on where to place it within my `for` loops? or am I totaly on the wrong path?

```
         <script>

            var table = "", rows = 1, cells = 1;

            for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                table += "<tr>";

                for (var c = 1; c <= cells; c++) {
                    table += "<td>" + c + "</td>"
                }

                table += "</tr>"

            }
            document.write("<table border =1>" + table + "</table>")
        </script>
```

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get "stairs" look-like table, the amounts of rows and cells should be equal. Example below is how to do it properly. In order to change amount of rows, change value of variable from 7 to what you want ;)

```
var table = "";
rows = 7;
for (var r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    for (var c = 1; c <= r; c++) {
        table += "<td>" + c + "</td>";
    }
    table += "</tr>";
}
document.write("<table border =1>" + table + "</table>");
```

Comment: This works!  I spent hours trying to figure this out! haha, 

Any chance you can talk me through this code? becuase I don't really understand why it works... hahah

Comment: Look, first for is going from r = 0 to rows = 7, as in example. Second for depends on first for and as a result it goes from c = 1 to the c = r (what we have in parent for) and as a result we got the stairs.